# Search last known update for each object in SQL

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, date, greatest-n-per-group

I have a 2 table : one storing objects (Object) and other storing updates of the state (for example: NOT_DONE, BEING_MANUFACTURED, DONE) of the objects (ObjectStateUpdate):
[database diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tk0sQ.png)

Each time an object change of state a line is added in the ObjectStateUpdate table with the new state and the date of the change of state.

In my application I have a use case where I want to retrieve all the objects that are in a specific state (let's say all the objects being manufactured).

This is done with a complex SQL request which gets the last known update for each object based on the date of the update and if two updates have occurred at the same time I use the id of the updates to find the last one (each object has at least one update of state):

```
SELECT * 
FROM ObjectStateUpdate 
WHERE id =
(
    SELECT MAX(id) 
    FROM ObjectStateUpdate 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT objectId, MAX(date) AS max_date 
        FROM trade_manager_app_orderupdate GROUP BY objectId
    ) as Latest 
    ON ObjectStateUpdate.objectId = Latest.objectId 
    AND ObjectStateUpdate.date = Latest.max_date 
    GROUP BY ObjectStateUpdate.objectId
)
```

I was thinking of adding a foreign key column `"lastUpdateId"` in the object table to store the id of the last update of the object (each time I have a new update I would store its id the object).

This could avoid having to do the big SQL request by replacing it with a much more efficient one, but I am afraid it would add an inconsistency in the database model if for some reason the "lastUpdateId" is not up to date with the data of the ObjectStateUpdate table.

So should I add this column to the object table to improve performance or should I keep it like this to avoid the inconsistency ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I followed you correctly, you can largely simplify your existing query using `row_number()` (if you version of SQLite supports them);

```
select *
from (
    select u.*, row_number() over(partition by objectId order by date desc, id desc) rn 
    from ObjectStateUpdate u
) t
where rn = 1 and state = 'BEING_MANUFACTURED'
```

You can get the same result with a correlated subquery:

You can get the same result with a correlated subquery:

```
select u.*
from ObjectStateUpdate u
where 
    id = (
        select u1.id
        from ObjectStateUpdate u1
        where u1.objectId = u.objectId
        order by date desc, id desc
        limit 1
    )
    and state = 'BEING_MANUFACTURED'
```

For performance, you want an index on `(objectId, date, id)`.